# Get emails, not MS Teams messages from MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I `GET` `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`, it returns messages I received in MS Teams.

How can I query for **only** emails using the MS Graph API?

Comment: I think the messages endpoint is only for emails. Is it possible you are receiving message notifications from teams in your inbox and mistaking them for the actual teams message?

Answer (score 0):

As AAvery said, I believe as well that Teams send you the messages to your Outlook after a while of inactivity. Try to remove those emails(notifications) from MS Teams and try to GET again.

Eventually, try this: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages/delta

Answer (score 0):

I came here to ask same question but I was able to get some clue which helped me to get my code working.

my old code:

```
    public async void ReadMails(IAuthenticationProvider authProvider)
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
            .Request()
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.Sender,
                e.Subject,
                e.Body
            })
            .GetAsync();

    }
```

New code code which reads only emails now.

```
    public async void ReadMails(IAuthenticationProvider authProvider)
    {
        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        var messages = await graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages
            .Request()
            .Select(e => new
            {
                e.Sender,
                e.Subject,
                e.Body
            })
            .GetAsync();

    }
```

I hope this helps.